# How to send Facebook values to next screen in Xcode 8, swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm putting together a series of registration pages where users are first presented with a "create account using Facebook" button, which logs them in, and then presents them with a basic registration page filled with empty text boxes. However, I am trying to populate some of these text boxes with the users' values gathered from the Graph Request.

Here is the first screen with the registration button:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class RegisterVC: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
var fbLoginSuccess = false

var fbName:String!
var fbEmail:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 82, y: 325, width: view.frame.width - 210, height: 59)

    loginButton.delegate = self
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("Did log out of facebook")
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    print("Successfully logged in")

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start {(connection, result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Failed to start graph request", err)
            return
        } else {

            guard let data = result as? [String:Any] else {return}

            let fbEmail = data["email"]
            let fbName  = data["name"]

            func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let vc = segue.destination as? CreateAccountVC
            vc!.email.text = self.fbEmail
            vc!.fullname.text = self.fbName
                }

        }

        print(result)
    }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "regSegue", sender: RegisterVC.self)
}
```

And these are the text boxes on the next screen:

```
import UIKit

class CreateAccountVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fullname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verifyEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verifyPassword: UITextField!
```

All the code above presents me with the registration page, but the text boxes are empty and not populated with the Facebook data. I'm not a great coder and really and help would be useful. Let me know if you have any solutions! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in this snippet:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let vc = segue.destination as? CreateAccountVC
            vc!.email.text = self.fbEmail
            vc!.fullname.text = self.fbName
```

`CreateAccountVC`s textfields have not been created at the moment when their `.text` attribute is being updated here, the textfields are `nil` at this point in time.
Evaluate passing the `String` objects retrieved from `Graph` API directly to `CreateAccountVC` & then using them to update the textfields.

Consider morphing existing implementation to something on these lines:

```
class CreateAccountVC: UIViewController {
    var fbName:String!
    var fbEmail:String!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
    ...
```

The snippet mentioned above here would change to:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                let vc = segue.destination as? CreateAccountVC
                vc!.fbName = self.fbName
                vc!.fbEmail = self.fbEmail
                ...
```

Comment: But would these changes populate the text entry boxes?

Comment: No, not yet. By performing the above changes, we are ensuring that _data_ is propagated correctly & reliably to successive `ViewController`s. Now, that we have the `string` data, we can update our textFields/labels, etc. A good place to do this would be in `-viewDidLoad` where we can set the `textField`s `.text` attribute as the received `string` objects.

Comment: In the viewdidload I simply set full name.text = fbName and the same for the emails but it did not change the text fields. Any suggestions on what to do?